# Export multiple tabs with ui-grid into excel

Tags: java, angularjs, excel, angular-ui-grid, hssfworkbook

I have multiple tabs, and each tab has a **ui-grid**.

I want to export each grid on click of a button, as a separate sheet in an excel workbook, maintaining each of the grids format in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in functionality to do this. However,
You can use [Alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql).

From each gridApi refer the 'data' array to export the contents.
[Example](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How-to-export-JavaScript-Array-of-Filtered-HTML-Table-data-to-MS-Excel-or-CSV)